# Convert DataTable(dynamic columns) into List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert DataTable with below sample Data

```
Employee subject1 subject2 subject3 .......
1        100      80         60......
2        90       70         70...
```

into

List.

Where Employee Object is as follows..

```
public class Employee
{
  public int EmpId { get; set;}
  public Dictionary<string,decimal> SubjectMarks;

}
```

Can anyone help me in converting this Datatable to List in c sharp or using linq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the dynamic subject-columns start at index 1 and end at `table.Columns-Count-1`. Then i would create an array of these columns first. Then you can use `Select` + `ToDictionary` + `ToList`:

```
DataColumn[] subjectColumns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(1).ToArray();
List<Employee> employee = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new Employee
    {
        EmpId = r.Field<int>("Employee"),
        SubjectMarks = subjectColumns.Select(c => new
        {
            Subject = c.ColumnName,
            Marks   = r.Field<decimal>(c)
        })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Subject, x => x.Marks)
    }).ToList();
```

Assuming that the type of the columns are already `int` for the ID and `decimal` for the marks. Otherwise use `int.Parse` and `decimal.Parse` to convert them.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var list = new List<Employee>();
    var id = table.Columns[0];
    var marks = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(1).ToArray();
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        var obj = new Employee { EmpId = (int) row[id] };
        var dict = new Dictionary<string,decimal>();
        foreach (var mark in marks)
        {
            dict[mark.ColumnName] = (decimal)row[mark];
        }
        obj.SubjectMarks = dict;
        list.Add(obj);
    }
```

Comment: I really like this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Approach look simple and tidy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Dictionary, then you can you List to add subject grades
Try this:

```
public class Employee
{
  public int EmpId { get; set;}
  public List<string> SubjectMarks { get; set;}
}


var empList = (from emp in dtEmployeeList.AsEnumerable()
               select new Employee()
               {
                   EmpId = (int) emp["Employee"],
                   SubjectMarks = List<string>() 
                   {
                       emp["subject1"].ToString(),
                       emp["subject2"].ToString(),
                       emp["subject3"].ToString()
                   }
               }).ToList()
```

Comment: SubjectMarks is not a `List<string>` it's a `Dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
System.Data.DataTable table = // your table 
List<Employee> result =
    table.AsEnumerable().Select(i => new Employee()
        {
            EmpId = i.Field<int>("Employee"),
            SubjectMarks = { { "subject1", i.Field<decimal>("subject1") } ,
                             { "subject2", i.Field<decimal>("subject2") } ,
                             { "subject3", i.Field<decimal>("subject3") } }
        }).ToList();
```

You'll need to make sure you have a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`. And don't forget to add the `using System.Data`.